# SQL Server CHECKSUM function issue

Tags: sql-server, checksum

Can anyone explain to me, and maybe propose a better approach.

Why is checksum(0.0280) = checksum(-0.0280) ?
Casting to float would solve it, but I’m reluctant to do it, and I would rather find a way around this.

LE: I was trying to keep things simple, as with most questions around here, this is something that has come up in production, and putting the entire database structure is a bit of an overkill. 
I will try to explain it a bit better. I have some dynamic structure tables (dynamic in the sense that the enduser controls the structure through a web application) that have the following rough structure: Id (int), StartDate, FKey1 (nvarchar), Value1 (decimal or nvarchar or int), Value2 ... ValueN.

This tables can be filled (again, by the end user) with redundant data (millions of rows) and during some calculations I would like to declutter this table leaving only relevant information. The way to declutter it, is to remove consecutive identical rows (except for the date). For the sake of performance I wanted to avoid checking each column individually, so CHECKSUM came in handy because it also supports multiple columns as input.

Comment: What do you mean "solve it"?   What are you trying to do?

Comment: for decimals in sql server, still a maze! if you don't specify the datatype (decimal or float), your results mostly will be incorrect. For instance, if you do `SELECT (1/100)` without casting you'll get a 0, cast one of them to decimal or float and you'll get 0.01. so you need to specify the datatype if you want to write a number in T-SQL directly. (so I assume that 0.0280 was read as 0 for both checksum, and casting to float or decimal will fix it.

Comment: I added some more details

Comment: _For the sake of performance I wanted to avoid checking each column individually, so CHECKSUM came in handy because it also supports multiple columns as input_. Properly indexed columns will definitely outperform a non indexed checksum column. Others have made many suggestions but it seems like none of them suit for performance reasons.

Comment: A common patter is to first use checksum to vastly reduce the number of matches then from that result, actually compare the individual columns to account for collisions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you were thinking that there is one and only one possible value for every possible CHECKSUM, you were mistaken.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017):

> If at least one of the values in the expression list changes, the list
>   checksum will probably change. However, this is not guaranteed.
>   Therefore, to detect whether values have changed, we recommend use of
>   CHECKSUM only if your application can tolerate an occasional missed
>   change.   Otherwise, consider using HashBytes instead. With a specified MD5 hash algorithm, the probability that HashBytes will return the same result, for two different inputs, is much lower compared to CHECKSUM.

If you want to research it further, you might Google `CHECKSUM collisions`.

Comment: I can tolerate collisions ... but this one is too close.

Comment: So try HashBytes, like the documentation suggests.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, unfortunately, HashBytes only accepts varchar, nvarchar, or varbinary and I need my solution to not require casting since these are pretty big tables.

Comment: I ended up using HashBytes, but with a trick to make it work for my scenario:
 HashBytes('SHA1', (select Column1, Column2, Column3 for xml raw))

Answer (score 0):

With a hashing function (like CHECKSUM) there will always be the risk of collisions.

You can try another (slower) hash function (like HashBytes as mentioned by @TabAlleman) or you can try out some homemade attempts that might perform better than HashBytes (but this should be tested), and that fits better to your anticipation of what numbers you expect coming in. So this is a trade-off: Performance versus collision risk. Here are 2 such homemade attempts that will give a different result for numbers that are equal except for the sign. Please notice that these variants will also produce collisions, but most likely for other differences than simply their sign.

```
select checksum(.028, floor(.28))
select checksum(-.028, floor(-.28))

select checksum(.028) + sign(.28)
select checksum(-.028) + sign(-.28)
```

When you said you could solve it by casting to a float, but still did not want to do that, I wonder if that was out of performance considerations. If so, I'm not sure my variants will perform better than casting to a float. Have a go at measuring that yourself :-)

Comment: Thank you for you answer. I will give the floor suggestion a try.
I'm reluctant to cast on account of performance, and I don't want to change the table's datatype as this would require a tone of work to adjust everywhere.

I've added some more details to the question to get a better understanding of my actual use-case.